# Working with onPause, onRestart, in Tab Widget - Android

Tags: android, multitasking, restart, tabwidget, onstart

I have a `ListView` that is inside a `TabWidget`. When I select an item on the `ListView` and go to the child `ListView`, the `TabWidget` disappears. This is fine, except that it invokes the `onPause` method, and thus causes `onRestart` to be called when I return to the parent `ListView`.

I have `onRestart` setup to retrieve updated data from the server, but I do not want this to occur everytime the user returns to the parent `ListView`. I only want `onRestart` to be called when the app comes alive from running in the background. I have tried implementing a Boolean variable to determine if I should execute the code that is inside `onRestart`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get around the effects of this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fire off your child activity with `startActivityForResult` and set a flag in `onActivityResult` to not reload (which should be called when the user backs into the listview from the detail page). You'd have a member variable (let's say `mReload`) that you'd set to `true` in `onCreate` and `onRestart`, and to `false` in `onActivityResult`, then process the reload `onResume` if `mReload` is true (and set it back to `false` so a normal resume won't trigger the reload).

Alternative: just set a flag (`mLeftPage`) in your activity on the row's click listener. On restart, if `mLeftPage` is true, don't reload the list and set `mLeftPage` back to false. Otherwise, reload.

Comment: Your 2nd (alternative) answer was easy to implement, my failure to get it right without asking this question was mainly a logic problem on my end. Thank You.